# Number of nodes of given height 'h' in an n element heap inconsistency

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, heap

The formula for the number of nodes of height 'h' in an 'n' element heap is given as ceil(n/2^(h+1)). For this given problem the number of nodes of height 2 as shown in figure is 2.
[image]

But from the formula, I get ceil(19/8) = 3.

Could someone help explain my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The formula for the number of nodes of height 'h' in an 'n' element heap is given as ceil(n/2^(h+1))

Can you provide your source?

If this is regarding [this problem](http://www.cs.sfu.ca/CourseCentral/307/petra/2009/SLN_2.pdf) (which I assume from your picture). It says:

A heap of size n has **at most** ceil(n/2^(h+1)) nodes with height h

Comment: Thanks Ajk_P for clarifying that the formula is 'at most' and not exactly! +1